# How to drop pins from top of iPhone when you use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate mkmapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, rotation, screen-rotation, pins

This one is causing me fits!  I have a view that contains a `mkmapview`  I want to be able to rotate the map view, leaving the enclosing navigationcontroller alone (i.e.: top of phone is top of navbar.

I am using this code -- which is working:

```
theMapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(( trueHeading  * M_PI / 180.0) * -1);


[UIView beginAnimations: @"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
CGFloat radians = trueHeading / 180 * M_PI;
compassRoseView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( radians);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I will also rotate the `mkannotationviews` in the `didUpdateHeading` delegate call...

My problem?  If I drop new annotations once (or after) the map is rotated, they do not drop from top of device (like they do in the **Maps app** when you rotate the map), instead the drop from "top" of the `mkmapview` -- which of course, because it is rotated, is no longer at the top of the device.

any ideas?